# Linux Date Function forward/backward time

Tags: linux, shell, date

Is there an option of date function?

How do I get LOAD_TEST_START to be 2 minutes forward?

How do I get LOAD_TEST_END to be 2 minutes back?

```
LOAD_TEST_START=$(date -u +%FT%TZ)
LOAD_TEST_END=$(date -u +%FT%TZ)
```

Comment: Get the epoch in seconds, add/subtract 120 seconds and then use date command to set those variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/365923/how-can-i-calculate-and-format-a-date-duration-using-gnu-tools-not-a-result-dat) answer helped me and works on the linux-version of `date`.

```
LOAD_TEST_START=$(date +%FT%TZ -d "2 minutes ago")
LOAD_TEST_END=$(date +%FT%TZ -d "2 minutes")
```

On macos/FreeBSD one can use

```
LOAD_TEST_START=$(date -v+2M +%FT%TZ)
LOAD_TEST_END=$(date -v-2M +%FT%TZ)
```

Comment: I got an error, in a POD, but your suggested command works on my MAC terminal
$ LOAD_TEST_START=$(date -v+1M +%FT%TZ)
date: invalid option -- 'v'.  
Kernel Version: 5.4.89+
Operating System: Alpine Linux v3.13 (containerized)
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64

Comment: Pardon, my bad. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you want, but you can get the current epoch value and then add/subtract 120 seconds (2 minutes) from it and convert the results back to date.

```
dateval=`date +%s`
echo "orig "`date -d @$dateval +%FT%T%Z`

start=`expr $dateval + 120`
end=`expr $dateval - 120`

LOAD_TEST_START=`date -d @$start +%FT%T%Z`
LOAD_TEST_END=`date -d @$end +%FT%T%Z`

echo "start "$LOAD_TEST_START
echo "end "$LOAD_TEST_END
```